# Haskell recursive function without stack overflow

Tags: haskell, recursion, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

I have a recursive function which index a textile and if I use it for huge textfiles, i'll get a stack space overflow. I thought because I put the recursive part in the let part I could avoid this stack space overflow, but I'm still getting it. What would be the best way to avoid a stack space overflow with this function?

```
--lines to Map

parseLinesToWordEntryMap :: Int -> [String] -> M.Map Word [TextLocation] -> (M.Map Word [TextLocation])
parseLinesToWordEntryMap lineNumber [] wordEntryMap  = wordEntryMap
parseLinesToWordEntryMap lineNumber (x:xs) wordEntryMap =
    let
         lineNumber' = lineNumber-1
         wordEntryMapRec = parseLinesToWordEntryMap lineNumber' xs wordEntryMap
    in
         parseLineToWordEntryMap lineNumber x wordEntryMapRec
```

Comment: It would help to know the definition of `parseLineToWordEntryMap `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have is essentially a right fold,

```
parseLinesToWordEntryMap lineNumber xs wordEntryMap
    = foldr update wordEntryMap (zip [lineNumber, lineNumber - 1 .. ] xs)
      where
        update (num,x) wordMap = parseLineToWordEntryMap num x wordMap
```

thus if `parseLineToWordEntryMap` is strict in its `Map` argument (fairly typical for `Map` arguments), nothing can be done before the end of the list is reached, and then the result is built going back to the beginning of the list.

If at all possible, you should consume the input the other way round, with a left fold, and make sure that the folded function has the right strictness, so that no large thunks are built.

For more specific suggestions, we'd need to see more of the code.

Comment: parseLineToWordEntryMap is function of this: Int -> String -> M.Map Word [TextLocation] -> M.Map Word [TextLocation]       I'm currently investigating foldl but don't know how to use it for my function, do you have an idea?

Comment: I'd need to know what the function _does_, how it's implemented. I suspect it just adds the line number to the `[TextLocation]` associated to the `String` (and inserts the `String` into the `Map` if not yet present). Then it's quite easy to transform it to a left fold. But I'd rather not speculate more without seeing what about.

Comment: Starting from Daniel Fischer's version, you would substitute foldl' (strict version in Data.List) for foldr, which would require flipping the arguments in the definition of update.  Then his other advice about strictness would need to be studied. Edit: I am adding a little speculation, now that I see he commented at the same time.

Comment: @Daniel your speculation is right, I sent you a message via BitBucket

Comment: @LeonS Indeed, a left fold is what's needed here. I'm rewriting now.

Comment: In addition to needing a left fold, the lazy subtraction "lineNumber' = lineNumber-1" is not obviously forced in that code snippet.  This could possibly build up too many layers if left this lazy.